# How to recover repository when hg recover aborts?

Tags: mercurial

Due to unknown reasons an HG command failed with the message:

> abort: abandoned transaction found - run hg recover!

But when I tried to use `recover` to get rid of the abandoned transaction, I got a different error:

```
$ hg recover
rolling back interrupted transaction
attempted to truncate path/to/file to 12345 bytes, but it was already 456 bytes
```

and it aborted. The actual file was named like:

```
_some_filename.cs.i
```

which is an internal HG data file. So it seems like the HG data records for `some_filename.cs` are badly clobbered. And indeed running `hg verify` shows errors like this:

```
# hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 warning: revlog 'data/project/folder/some_filename.cs.i' not in fncache!
 13691: empty or missing project/folder/some_filename.cs
 project/folder/some_filename.cs@13691: manifest refers to unknown revision b269f6036278
 project/folder/some_filename.cs@13741: manifest refers to unknown revision 651b96abf6da
 ...
```

(goes on for a long time)

which corroborates that the file is damaged but doesn't do anything useful to fix it.

`hg recover --help` doesn't show anything else that I can do...

And aside from the apparent damage to this one file, no ordinary HG commands work at this point. All of them report the repository is damaged. How can I recover from this?

Answer (score 2):

I concluded that this was just a situation that HG was not designed to deal with. For whatever reason HG's internal data file (the `.i` file) was destroyed.

It was helpful to review the HG source code which produced the key error:

```
if fp.tell() < o:
    raise error.Abort(
        _(
            b"attempted to truncate %s to %d bytes, but it was "
            b"already %d bytes\n"
        )
        % (f, o, fp.tell())
    )
```

(https://fossies.org/linux/mercurial/mercurial/transaction.py)

I'm not especially familiar with HG internals but this seemed to make it clear enough that HG was not able to handle the situation (understandably - arbitrary destruction of one of its data files leaves few options!).

The best workaround I could come up with was to manually copy the damaged `.i` file from another copy of the repository (on another PC). I didn't actually have local changes to that source file, so this seemed reasonable.

I copied the file (replacing the damaged original having made a backup first).

Then ran `hg recover`. **This was now able to resolve the original "abandoned transaction" issue.** Other HG commands work as well.

Worth noting that running `hg verify` still reports some errors (though many fewer). Perhaps the history of this single file is still not right; ultimately I think I will need to re-clone this repository but at least I can complete my immediate tasks without losing any work.